# Editing the Action bar of the selected theme

Tags: android, xml

I have selected an empty theme.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GAo5.png)

The how can I apply the padding to the action Bar (component containing text tempapp) containing text 'tempapp'.

Can I edit that action bar?

Comment: See the image that i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Toolbar Instead. You can customize it according to your wish.

In your app gradle add this to dependency and Sync:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

In style.xml:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
```

In layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="20dp" <!-- example -->
      app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In activity:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);          
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working ....But,in layout folder, in which xml filw we have to add <android.support.... /> ?                                                                 In which file we have to add Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);   ?

Comment: add <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> to activity_home_temp.xml and
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); to HomeTemp.java in onCreate().

Comment: it is showing me error ..can not resolve symbol 'Toolbar'

Comment: You should add toolbar in a parent Layout(LinearLayout or RelativeLayout). Please show your activity_home_temp.xml code :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the dependency. Now have edited my answer. Please check the updated answer and re-build and run.

Comment: What is the use of that dependency

Comment: and why we have to addit

Comment: To recognize the Toolbar and it's functionalities. Did you find the app gradle file ?

Comment: there are to gradle files..Project:tempapp

Comment: the other one, which starts with "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

Comment: After adding the dependency there will appear a "Sync Now" link at the right corner. Click there and your Toolbar will be recognized.

Comment: yep , the dependece is already adde..thank...but i got another error when i rebuilt the program..error: Error:(365, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorGreen'.

Comment: Where did you add 'colorGreen' ? I've no idea. Show the code.

Comment: this is my style.xml                                                                                                            <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorGreen">@color/colorGreen</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: check if you have a color named "colorGreen" in values/colors.xml. If not add this : <color name="colorGreen">#FF37DC0E</color>

Comment: In where are you getting the error ? (which xml file) ? Please elaborate

Comment: where is the option?

Comment: there is a tick mark at the left side of my answer ( under the 0). Click it please.

Comment: Thanks, it may help others in future.